# Android, why ever use Button views, since every view can have an onclicklistener

Tags: android, button, view

I am curious, why would I ever use Button or ImageButton, when TextViews, ImageViews, and everything else all can have onclicklisteners, all can have src's and background attributes, states and everything else that a Button or ImageButton offers

I might be missing something, so please reveal what it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no differences, except default style. `ImageButton` has a non-null background by default.

Also, `ImageButton.onSetAlpha()` method always returns false, `scaleType` is set to `center` and it's always inflated as focusable.

Here's `ImageButton`'s default style:

```
 <style name="Widget.ImageButton">
     <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
     <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
     <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
     <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Each one has different styles, that's it. You can create a simple `TextView` and users still can click on it and you can respond to those clicks... but `TextView` does not offer by default any visual feedback.

In fact, a `Button` is just a `TextView` with a set of selector drawables.